# Get WooCommerce customer ID by email address

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a PHP function or method in WooCommerce for getting the `customerID` by email address opposite the `userID`?

I get the `user` and the `userID` by email address like this:

```php
$customer = get_user_by( 'email', 'user@example.com' );
```

[get_user_by()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/) - Retrieve user info by a given field

---

But customers don't have a `userID`, so I assume that customers have a `customerID` instead?

If so, how can I get this `customerID` by email address?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [WPDB](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) methods and a custom function to `select` the `customer_id` from the `wc_customer_lookup` table by `$email`

```php
function get_customer_id_by_email( $email ) {
    // Empty, return
    if ( empty ( $email ) ) return;
    
    // Global
    global $wpdb;
    
    // Result, select from "wc_customer_lookup"
    $result = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT customer_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wc_customer_lookup
        WHERE email = %s
    ", $email ) );

    // NOT empty
    if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
        return $result;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

---

```php
// Call function
$customer_id = get_customer_id_by_email( 'user@example.com' );

echo $customer_id;
```